# How can I reverse geocode with google maps api?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I am using the following code to display google maps on my website with autocomplete functionality.

I would like to be able to reverse geocode using the longitude and latitude and echo the address on my page.

How is this implemented am I on the right path?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
          zoom: 17,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          mapOptions);

        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          draggable: true
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
          infowindow.close();
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
          }

         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function (event) {
                var point = marker.getPosition();
                map.panTo(point);
                document.getElementById("latitude").value = point.lat();
                document.getElementById("longitude").value = point.lng();
            });

          var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
              place.icon,
              new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              new google.maps.Size(35, 35));
          marker.setIcon(image);
          marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);

          var address = '';
          if (place.address_components) {
            address = [(place.address_components[0] &&
                        place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                       (place.address_components[1] &&
                        place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                       (place.address_components[2] &&
                        place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                      ].join(' ');

          }

          infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });


      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this for Google Reverse Geocoding:

[Reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Reverse Geocoding</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        width: 350px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
      #latlng {
        width: 225px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <input id="latlng" type="text" value="40.714224,-73.961452">
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Reverse Geocode">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997}
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
          geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
        });
      }

      function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
        var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
        var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
        var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
        geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            if (results[0]) {
              map.setZoom(11);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
              });
              infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
              window.alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```