# Google geocode - translate address to English

Tags: google-maps, reverse-geocoding

Is it possible to use reverse geocoding for address translation ?

I can't find in the request parameter's any reference to language.

Regards,
Arie.

Answer (score 0):

Just pointing other already answered sources:

(Although the answer is obtained by simply google searching...)

[How can I reverse geocode with google maps api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806868)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

Answer (score -1):

are you asking for this ?

```
function geocodePosition(pos) {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          geocoder.geocode({
            latLng: pos
          }, function(responses) {
            if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
              document.getElementById('event_venue').value = responses[0].formatted_address;
            } else {
              alert('Cannot determine address at this location.');
            }
          });
        }
```